# Recursive walking through a PHP multidimensional array to make a comparison

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have a large array converted from a JSON structure with an unknown number of elements and sublevels.

Something like:

```
$marr = array
(
    "Order" => array
    (
        "Details" => array
        (
            "Document" => array
            (
                "Number" => "1585636772",
                "Date" => "2014-12-31"
            ),
            "Delivery" => array
            (
                "Date" => "2015-01-02",
                "TrackingCode" => "5703",
                "Name" => "Example Name",
                "Address" => "Example Address"
            )
        )
    )
);
```

And on the other hand, I have an array of items I need to compare and find out if they are in the array above.  This "indexer" will always mirror the same structure above (it's generated before the comparison step) because I thought that would help me ensure a proper comparison in an easier way.

Something like:

```
$indexer = array
(
    "Order" => array
    (
        "Details" => array
        (
            "Document" => array
            (
                "Date" => "variable_name_1"
            ),
            "Delivery" => array
            (
                "Date" => "variable_name_2"
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I'm not entirely sure how best to compare these.  I have looked into *array_walk_recursive()* which only returns the leaf values and I have tried to write my own attempts at a basic recursive function that would perform a *foreach()* which would then try to do something like:

```
if( isset($marr["Order"]["Details"]["Document"]["Date"]) )
{
    $store[ $indexer["Order"]["Details"]["Document"]["Date"] ] = $marr["Order"]["Details"]["Document"]["Date"];
}
```

So that at the end I would have a basic array that stored all values found on *$marr* under an alias that was listed on *$indexer*.  Like this:

```
$store["variable_name_1"] = "2014-12-31";
$store["variable_name_2"] = "2015-01-02";
```

This has been a headache for two days now and I can't seem to figure out the best way to go through this.  I'm trying to walk through $indexer to reach its ending, obtain the "variable name", and then compare with $marr to store its data, but I always seem to lose the parent nodes of $indexer while trying to do this recursively.  I would appreciate any advice at all.

Comment: How do you get `"variable_name_1"` and two? Do these names matter?

Comment: Not sure, why you need an recursive function.. Just create an nested loop

Comment: @Kalkran those names are in $indexer, they are in theory needed because I want to store the data from the JSON web service to use in a bunch of SQL queries.  They are just example names here, in theory I could have, says, twenty of these to use in five different queries.  But that's a different logic step for the application I'm trying to build and not relevant here, I imagine.

Comment: @Philipp I don't think a basic nested loop would work here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this recursive function:

```
function storeFromIndex($marr, $indexer) {
    if (!is_array($indexer)) {
        return array($indexer => $marr);
    }
    $store = [];
    foreach($indexer as $key => $subindexer) {
        $store = array_merge($store, storeFromIndex($marr[$key], $subindexer));
    }
    return $store;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
$store = storeFromIndex($marr, $indexer);
```

With the example data given, *$store* will be:

```
array (
  'variable_name_1' => '2014-12-31',
  'variable_name_2' => '2015-01-02',
)
```

Comment: Jesus, it's perfect in its simplicity!  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Here I would like to suggest do not maintain indexer, you can use iterator and create new array using associated keys.

For example have a look on below solution:

```
$array = array
(
    "Order" => array
    (
        "Details" => array
        (
            "Document" => array
            (
                "Number" => "1585636772",
                "Date" => "2014-12-31"
            ),
            "Delivery" => array
            (
                "Date" => "2015-01-02",
                "TrackingCode" => "5703",
                "Name" => "Example Name",
                "Address" => "Example Address"
            )
        )
    )
);


$new_array = array();
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));

foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    $keys = array();
    $keys[] = $key;
    for ($i = $iterator->getDepth() - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $keys[] = $iterator->getSubIterator($i)->key();
    }
    $key_paths = array_reverse($keys);
    $new_array[implode('_', $key_paths)] = $value;
}

print_r($array);
print_r($new_array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [Order] => Array
        (
            [Details] => Array
                (
                    [Document] => Array
                        (
                            [Number] => 1585636772
                            [Date] => 2014-12-31
                        )

                    [Delivery] => Array
                        (
                            [Date] => 2015-01-02
                            [TrackingCode] => 5703
                            [Name] => Example Name
                            [Address] => Example Address
                        )

                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [Order_Details_Document_Number] => 1585636772
    [Order_Details_Document_Date] => 2014-12-31
    [Order_Details_Delivery_Date] => 2015-01-02
    [Order_Details_Delivery_TrackingCode] => 5703
    [Order_Details_Delivery_Name] => Example Name
    [Order_Details_Delivery_Address] => Example Address
)
```

Comment: This isn't a bad solution and I wasn't aware of those recursive iterator classes, thanks.